# Golang x/net/websocket creating header starts new console for few secconds

Tags: windows, go, websocket

Hello i have a problem with my small applications that runs as system tray. I use x/net/websocket library. But if i add headers new console starts (1 new header = 1 console for few secconds). On linux that works fine without console. On windows with using `GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui-ldflags -H=windowsgui` that error happens. That's sample code where it happens

```golang
package main

func main() {
origin := "http://localhost/"
URL    := "ws://myserveripaddress:PORT/"
config, _ := websocket.NewConfig(URL, origin)

config.Header.Set("Type", "premium")
config.Header.Set("Auth", "1234-1234-9123")

socket, err := websocket.DialConfig(config)

if err != nil {
    log.println(err.Error())
}
}
```

Connecting to my server works perfectly

Comment: Not a lot to be seen in this code: Can you post the error>

Comment: I don't get any error's. Just if i add headers new console appear for few secconds

Comment: Your main function exits after the log. There is not listener (aka long term process) defined. You have to start a listener on the socket.

Comment: i have listener on my project. That's just part of code. Just need to find how to fix that new header creates console for few secconds